# Optaplanner: Penalize ConstraintStream at Multiple Levels

Tags: optaplanner

I have a domain model where I penalize a score at multiple levels within a single rule. Consider a cloud scheduling problem where we have to assign processes to computers, but each process can be split amongst several computers. Each process has a threshold (e.g. 75%), and we can only "win" the process if we can schedule up to its threshold. We get some small additional benefit from scheduling the remaining 25% of the process, but our solver is geared to "winning" as many processes as possible, so we should be scheduling as many processes as possible to their threshold before scheduling the remainder of the process.

Our hard rule counts hard constraints (we can't schedule more processes on a computer than it can handle)

Our medium rule is rewarded for how many processes have been scheduled up to the threshold (no additional reward for going above 75%).

Our soft rule is rewarded for how many processes have been scheduled total (here we do get additional reward for going above 75%).

This scoring implementation means that it is more important to schedule all processes up to their threshold than to waste precious computer space scheduling 100% of a process.

When we used a drools implementation, we had a rule which rewarded the medium and soft levels simultaneously.

```
when
   $process : Process()
   $percentAllocated : calculatePercentProcessAllocated($process) //uses an accumulator over all computers
then
   mediumReward;
   if ($percentAllocated > $process.getThreshold()) {
      mediumReward = $process.getThreshold();
   }
   else {
      mediumReward = $percentAllocated;
   }
   softReward = $percentAllocated;
   scoreHolder.addMultiConstraintMatch(0, mediumReward, softReward);
```

The above pseudo-drools is heavily simplified, just want to show how we were rewarded two levels at once.

The problem is that I don't see any good way to apply multi constraint matches using constraint streams. All the examples I see automatically add a terminator after applying a penalize or reward method, so that no further score modifications can be made. The only way I see to implement my rules is to make two rules which are identical outside of their reward calls.

I would very much like to avoid running the same constraint twice if possible, so is there a way to penalize the score at multiple levels at once?

Also to anticipate a possible answer to this question, it is not possible to split our domain model so that each process is two processes (one process from 0% to the threshold, and another from the threshold to 100%). Part of the accumulation that I have glossed over involves linking the two parts and would be too expensive to perform if they were separate objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way in the constraint streams API to do that. Constraint weights are assumed to be constant.

If you must do this, you can take advantage of the fact that there really is no "medium" score. The medium part in `HardMediumSoftScore` is just another level of soft. Therefore `0hard/1medium/2soft` would in practice behave the same as `0hard/1000002soft`. If you pick a sufficiently high constant to multiply the medium part with, you can have `HardSoftScore` work just like `HardMediumSoftScore` and implement your use case at the same time.

Is it a hack? Yes. Do I like it? No. But it does solve your issue.

Another way to do that would be to take advantage of node sharing. I'll use an example that will show it better than a thousand words:

```
UniConstraintStream<Person> stream = constraintFactory.forEach(Person.class);
Constraint one = stream.penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE).asConstraint("Constraint 1")
Constraint two = stream.penalize(HardSoftScore.TEN).asConstraint("Constraint 2")
```

This looks like two constraints executing twice. And in CS-Drools, it is exactly that. But CS-Bavet can actually optimize this and will only execute the stream once, applying two different penalties at the end.

This is not a very nice programming model, you lose the fluency of the API and you need to switch to the non-default CS implementation. But again - if you absolutely need to do what you want to do, this would be another way.

Comment: Just to make sure I get it right, is there anything special that I have to do to let Bavet know that it can optimize those two constraints which share everything except `penalize`? Is it sufficient to simply return `one` and `two` from your example in the Constraint array in the `defineConstraints` method, then Bavet will do the rest?

Comment: Exactly. As easy as that.